# UI didn't update with React-redux on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, user-interface, react-redux

The problem shows on Mac OS and it works well on Windows.

It's a demo. When the button is clicked, the number of `count` did not increase, still 0. But when viewing the state in react dev-tool, the state value `count really increased when the button was clicked. And the reducer is a pure function, when state change, it's just generating a new object.

Below is the **code**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'

// React component
class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value, onIncreaseClick } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{value}</span>
        <button onClick={onIncreaseClick}>Increase</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Action
const increaseAction = { type: 'increase' }

// Reducer
function counter(state = { count: 0 }, action) {
  const count = state.count
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increase':
      return { count: count + 1 }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// Store
const store = createStore(counter)

// Map Redux state to component props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    value: state.count
  }
}

// Map Redux actions to component props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onIncreaseClick: () => dispatch(increaseAction)
  }
}

// Connected Component
const App = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I think it's simple in the code. But I can not tell why. The problem just happens on Mac OS, both Chrome and Safari.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Your reducer looks suspicious to me.

Comment: show your full App component code ?

Comment: your code works seemlessly. https://codesandbox.io/s/p90okzonj0

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri The code really works well on windows OS, which I tried. But the problem happened on MacOS, both in chrome and safari.

Comment: Do you receive any error message. because its quite possible that you may have not followed caseSensitivity with files or components in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works perfectly. I think there must be some javascript issues which is preventing the code to work, cause could be other files of your project. Please check those or you can share your project code.